# What is Domain\UserName.DATABLE in my SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a legacy system and I have a bunch of tables that starts with

```
Domain\UserName.DATETABLE
```

I have no dependencies on these tables, any idea, why & how these tables get generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These tables are created when users execute the `CREATE TABLE DATETABLE (...)` DDL statement.

By default, if the user is not a DBO, but does have the CREATE TABLE permission, they will create a table in a separate schema named after themselves. So instead of being called `dbo.DATETABLE` it is called `[DOMAIN\UserName].DATETABLE`.

Comment: Hi Ben, many thanks to your response. As I've mentioned there are no dependencies, so how these gets executed? are there any sql server transactions that might trigger the execution? And what is it used for?

Comment: Safi, someone has created them by uttering the magic words `CREATE TABLE`. It is as simple as that. Perhaps they may have used SQL Enterprise Manager, Visual Studio, or another tool.